# DataGrab - is there a hook?

Tags: hook, datagrab

Is there a hook at the completion of a DataGrab import? I need to run a script after an import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like DataGrab has three hooks:

- `ajw_datagrab_pre_import`
- `ajw_datagrab_modify_data`
- `ajw_datagrab_post_import`

If you open up `datagrab_model.php` and search for `active_hook` you will find them.

I haven't ever used them myself and I don't see any documentation on them. But they're worth a shot!

And as the developer himself pointed out in his comment below, the one you are after is `ajw_datagrab_post_import` so it sounds like you're in business.

Comment: `ajw_datagrab_post_import` will run after an import has been run. They're undocumented because they may change :)